LineChart from react-native-gifted-charts has margin on the left
I am making a line chart using react-native-gifted-charts, but there seems to be a margin on the left side of the chart that i cant remove. I've looked through the linechart properties but can't find anything about this gap.
Image of the chart issue
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
    <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: colors.background }]}>
      <View style={styles.upper}>
        <View style={[styles.ChartContainer, { backgroundColor: colors.darkestAccent }]}>
          <LineChart 
          data = {data} 
          width={screenWidth * 0.9}
          height={220}
          adjustToWidth={true}
          backgroundColor={'transparent'}
          isAnimated={false}
          initialSpacing={0}
          endSpacing={0}
          color={colors.colorAccent}
          hideDataPoints={true}
          pointerConfig={Pointer}
          focusEnabled={true}
          hideYAxisText={true}
          hideRules={true}
          hideOrigin={true}
          yAxisIndicesColor={false}
          hideAxesAndRules={true}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.lower}>
        <Link href={'/log'} asChild>
        <Button 
        dark={true} 
        icon="plus" 
        mode="contained" 
        rippleColor={colors.darkerAccent} 
        style={{ backgroundColor: colors.lightAccent }}
        contentStyle={{ height: 60, width: 240 }}
        labelStyle={{  fontSize: 18 }}
        >
          Log Excercise
        </Button>
        </Link>
      </View>
    </View>

Here is my stylesheet incase that is also necessary:
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  upper: {
    flex: 9,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
  },
  lower: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  ChartContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flex: 0.75,
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: '90%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});


The small margin on the left can be removed by using yAxisLabelWidth={0}
